# Batch file FOR command skipping lines

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I need some help with the FOR command in batch filing. What I want to do is read the file "Test.txt" and read only the third line and turn it into a usable variable within this batch file. Here is what I have attempted but it didn't work.

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in (Test.txt) do (
  set %%a=%LineThree%
)
```

When I run the program it says "The system cannot find the file Test.txt. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your script in the same directory as `Test.txt`?

Comment: Maybe if you added a full pathname to Test.txt: "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Test.txt" for example.

Comment: You should write a `cd` (without params) in the first line to check the current directory. This will differ depending on how and where you start your batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error indicates that your file `Test.txt` is not in the same directory you are running your script from.
2. To better accomplish grabbing just the third line from a text file, try the following, which will run quickly on **ANY** size file, instead of having to run through an entire file as yours would (and yours would incorrectly... you are actually grabbing *every third line*).

   (for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do set /p LineThree=) < Test.txt

   echo %LineThree%

As mentioned in another comment, you might want to try the full path to the file instead of just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is the missing quotes from **in (...)**

It should be:

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ('Test.txt') do (
  set %%a=%LineThree%
)
```

If still not works, try to write the full path for **`Test.txt`** (as others suggested)